# Is there a way to count the average of only existing products in sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to create a store program and I've run into a problem that I need your help to solve.  The program Inserts into a database a row with the following information into the table StoringTF:

- The store place code (For the company)
- The store's name (According to the code)
- The Date of entry
- The Product's code
- The Product's name
- The Incoming quantity
- The Unit Buying Price
- The total Buying Price
- The Outgoing Quantity
- The Unit Sell Price
- The Total Sell Price
- The Description of the entry

I want the unit sell Price to be automatically set to the average of the unit buying price of the same product 
I've tried using this code

```
c.execute("""WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Product_Name, AVG(Unit_Buying_Price) AS AveragePrice 
FROM StoringTF 
GROUP BY Product_Name
)
UPDATE StoringTF
SET Unit_Selling_Price = (
SELECT AveragePrice
FROM cte
WHERE Product_Name = StoringTF.Product_Name 
)""")
```

but It does 2 things wrong.

1. It updates all previous values in the table for the same product
   which is not true.
2. It calculates the average for non-existing products which makes
   the store value wrong.

I expect the output to be like this.

1. I want it to insert it for that row being inserted only and not
   edit previous rows
2. The second I want it to calculate it for existing products only

For example: 
If I got a monitor 3 months ago for 1000$
and then I sold it (so the average is 1000$ which is good)
then today I got that same monitor for 2000$.
I want the average to be 2000$ and not 1500$.

This is the schema of the table to make things clearer.

```
c.execute("""
CREATE TABLE StoringTF (
Store_code INTEGER,
Store TEXT,
Product_Date TEXT,
Permission INTEGER,
Product_Code INTEGER,
Product_Name TEXT,
Incoming INTEGER,
Unit_Buying_Price INTEGER,
Total_Buying_Price INTEGER,
Outgoing INTEGER,
Unit_Sell_Price INTEGER,
Total_Sell_Price INTEGER,
Description TEXT)
        """)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally realized the intent of the original question only after constructing a normalized schema and writing my other answer and getting clarifying comments from the OP.  I don't apologize for my other answer, because it was easy to assume that all of the problems had to do with non-normalized tables and misunderstanding what "existing" meant.  There was also confusion about updates vs inserts and storing calculated data instead of using queries on normalized tables, etc.  Eventually I realized that "existing" means "in stock" or "on hand" products...

**The original problem was to get the average price of only items not yet sold (a.k.a in stock, on hand); or in other words, to get the average price for only the most recently purchased items.**

This is no trivial query since purchases and sales can occur at differing quantities, and there could be remaining items in stock that "divide" a single purchase transaction.  Besides that particular challenge, one key idea is that this must be done with **multiple subqueries**.  In the case of sqlite we can use Common Table Expressions (CTE) that are essentially named subqueries:

1. One set of subqueries gets the total purchases (incoming) quantity and total sold (outgoing) quantities, where the difference of these is the stocked (i.e. "existing") quantity.
2. The other query must calculate a running sum to determine the critical transaction at which all previous inventory has been sold.  It is very likely that such critical values will not fall exactly on transaction boundaries, so the critical purchase transaction will be divided between some sold and some in-stock quantities.  Although running sums can be obtained using classic SQL constructs, sqlite supports Window Functions (i.e. OVER clause) which I use.

*Mathematical Note*: An average over an entire sample CANNOT be obtained by calculating the simple average of multiple partial averages.  Instead, either the partial averages need to be *weighted*, or the entire sample needs to be summed and the average calculated directly.  The easiest approach here was to simply sum values (i.e. prices) and quantities separately for calculating the overall average directly.  This approach avoids having to separately calculate weights for individual averages and pass them between queries.

Finally before the actual queries, some assumptions I made based on uncertainty about the schema and data.  The following code:

- assumes there is **a single** incoming transaction per Product_Date.  If that is not true, then the table needs more information (a unique ID or timestamp) to properly
  sort and distinguish between transactions so that multiple transactions are not
  selected as the critical-point for determining "existing" (i.e. stocked) products.
- assumes the total outgoing quantity is never greater than total incoming quantities as of any particular Product_Date / TransactionDate. If this is ever false according to the actual data, the results will certainly be inaccurate and may return bogus amounts.

The following is meant to work with the question's original schema.  **This query alone only provides the desired average purchase price.**  If you want to use this to insert a new incoming/sales record with the average as the unit sales price, then you must combine this query with another insert query.  There are various ways to do this, including *saving this as an sqlite View* or perhaps continuing the chain of CTE's for reference in the INSERT statement.  This exercise is left to you.

```sql
WITH sums AS (
        -- First get quantity sums for calculating stocked quantities
        SELECT Store_code, Product_Code, 
               ifnull(sum(Outgoing), 0) AS sold, sum(Incoming) AS purchased,
               sum(Incoming) - ifnull(sum(Outgoing), 0) AS stocked
        FROM StoringTF
        GROUP BY Store_code, Product_Code 
     ),
     runningIncomingD AS (
        -- Get a running sum of most-recently purchased items
        SELECT Store_code, Product_Code, Product_Date, Incoming, Unit_Buying_Price,
               sum(Incoming) OVER winStocked as purchased
        FROM StoringTF
        WHERE Incoming > 0 -- Purchased rows only
        WINDOW winStocked AS (PARTITION BY Store_code, Product_Code ORDER BY Product_Date DESC)
        ORDER BY Store_code, Product_Code, Product_Date DESC
     ),
     instockAll AS (
       SELECT r.Store_code, r.Product_Code,
              -- First case is for transactions that are purely in stock (not sold)
              -- Else case is for the critical transaction with partially sold items
              CASE WHEN r.purchased <= s.stocked  THEN r.Incoming
                   ELSE (s.stocked - (r.purchased - r.incoming)) END
              AS stocked,
              CASE WHEN r.purchased <= s.stocked  THEN r.Incoming * r.Unit_Buying_Price
                   ELSE (s.stocked - (r.purchased - r.incoming)) * r.Unit_Buying_Price END
              AS total_price              
       FROM runningIncomingD r INNER JOIN sums s
              ON s.Store_code == r.Store_code AND s.Product_Code == r.Product_Code

       -- Select only transactions that contain quantities not yet sold ("existing")
       WHERE r.purchased - s.stocked < r.incoming
       ORDER BY r.Store_code, r.Product_Code, r.Product_Date DESC
     )
SELECT Store_code, Product_Code,
       -- Get sums of both prices and quantities, then calculate the overall average
       sum(stocked) AS stocked, round(sum(total_price) / sum(stocked), 2) AS ave_price
FROM instockAll
GROUP BY Store_code, Product_Code
ORDER BY Store_code, Product_Code
```

---

The following is the equivalent query for the normalized schema I posted in the other question.  It is almost identical, only that it must separately sum the two Sales and Purchases transaction tables.

```sql
WITH salesSums AS (
        SELECT Store_code, Product_Code, sum(Quantity) AS sold
        FROM Sales
        GROUP BY Store_code, Product_Code 
     ),
     purchaseSums AS (
        SELECT Store_code, Product_Code, sum(Quantity) AS purchased
        FROM Purchases
        GROUP BY Store_code, Product_Code 
     ),
     sums AS (
        SELECT p.Store_code, p.Product_Code, 
        ifnull(s.sold, 0), p.purchased, p.purchased - ifnull(s.sold, 0) AS stocked
        FROM purchaseSums p LEFT JOIN salesSums s
             ON p.Store_code = s.Store_code AND p.Product_Code = s.Product_Code
     ),
     runningIncomingD AS (
        SELECT Store_code, Product_Code, TransactionDate, Quantity, Unit_Buying_Price,
               sum(Quantity) OVER winStocked as purchased
        FROM Purchases
        WINDOW winStocked AS (PARTITION BY Store_code, Product_Code ORDER BY TransactionDate DESC)
        ORDER BY Store_code, Product_Code, TransactionDate DESC
     ),
     instockAll AS (
       SELECT r.Store_code, r.Product_Code,
              CASE WHEN r.purchased <= s.stocked  THEN r.Quantity
                   ELSE (s.stocked - (r.purchased - r.Quantity)) END
              AS stocked,
              CASE WHEN r.purchased <= s.stocked  THEN r.Quantity * r.Unit_Buying_Price
                   ELSE (s.stocked - (r.purchased - r.Quantity)) * r.Unit_Buying_Price END
              AS total_price              
       FROM runningIncomingD r INNER JOIN sums s
              ON s.Store_code == r.Store_code AND s.Product_Code == r.Product_Code
       WHERE r.purchased - s.stocked < r.Quantity
       ORDER BY r.Store_code, r.Product_Code, r.TransactionDate DESC
     )
SELECT Store_code, Product_Code,
       sum(stocked) AS stocked, round(sum(total_price) / sum(stocked), 2) AS ave_price
FROM instockAll
GROUP BY Store_code, Product_Code
ORDER BY Store_code, Product_Code
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it . I've got a little question. If I have more than one transaction then I just replace every `Product_date` with `rowid` or whatever unique ID I add to the table is that right ? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Yes and no, because once again the question does not include enough detail or data examples to really know how to answer that for your data.  Rowid can be used to uniquely identify rows, so that is sufficient in many instances.  But my queries already consider that there are more than one transaction and that each transaction has a different date.  Although the rowid theoretically increments in over time, it is still just an abstract integer value.  A date value is a better way to sort transactions especially if you want to know what price values are older versus which are more recent.

Comment: If you mean that you have more than one transaction per date, then you need to use **both** the Product_Date AND rowid to sort records.  The queries would need to be updated to take that into consideration.  An alternative approach would be to ensure that the Product_Date field also includes a time (potentially down to the millisecond) to ensure transactions could be sorted and identified using a single field.

Comment: I think the second approach is better.  Sorting by date will make comparing prices over time more efficient and easy. I will set Product_Date to be datetime down to milliseconds because there can be multiple transactions per day. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. It updates all previous values in the table for the same product which is not true.

You must specify *exactly* which records that you want to update.  The database does not have an automatic concept of "previous" values, even if you have a date field or have multiple rows with the same `Product_Name`.  The statement does exactly what you told it to do... update *any and all* rows which match names according to `WHERE Product_Name = StoringTF.Product_Name`.  Why would you expect it to do anything otherwise?

> 2. It calculates the average for non-existing products which makes the store value wrong.

This is essentially the exact same issue as the first:  The database will include any and all rows that match your condition.  You said to only group on `Product_Name` so that is what it did.  Once again there is no automatic concept of "non-existing" product.  *You must add something to your WHERE clause and/or update the GROUP BY clause to distinguish existing products from non-existing products.*  You did not even provide enough detail for another person to determine that fact, so how would the database know to exclude "non-existing" products?

> 1. I want it to insert it for that row being inserted only and not edit previous rows

Your code executes an UPDATE statement.  If you want to **insert** a new row, then you need to do exactly that... execute an INSERT statement.  An UPDATE statement updates existing rows.  An INSERT statement inserts new rows.

> 2. The second I want it to calculate it for existing products only

Same answer for the first two points.

---

I suggest researching data normalization.  The basic idea about data normalization is to avoid redundant and duplicate information.  In a relational database, this is done by creating multiple tables that are linked with primary and foreign keys.

For instance, in one table you define the products with only information that does not change over time... something like a Product_Name or Product_Code and assigns a unique ProductID values to each row.  Define a separate table for each Store with various store details and an unique primary key StoreID value.

In another table is where you store transactions like buying and selling.  The transaction table would include foreign key ProductID and StoreID columns.  You don't actually store product or store details in the transaction table, only dollar amounts and other transaction details.  All details about the products and store are retrieved via the foreign key ID values.  Even better is to split sales and purchases into separate tables, but that is one more advanced step.

More suggestions begin to go beyond the scope of this one question, but there are other ways to normalize transactional data so that it becomes easier to get up-to-date averages and to select "only current products", etc.

---

### Proposed Partial Solution

Despite my better judgement I'm posting more detail that I hope will be useful.   StackOverflow in general has become much more open and tolerable about posting long, full solutions.

The following is not a full solution by any means, but it contains a sample schema and queries that could be used as part of a full solution.  All necessary details are *not* clear from the question, but the following demonstrates some level of normalization.  I of course do not include any migration query for existing data, since such effort and details should be handled by the OP.

**This still does not answer the question of selecting "only existing products" because that is something you need to define further.**  I have no idea what "only existing products means".  Do you mean only items in stock?  It is not clear from your table schema if your are storing total items in each row or whether each row is a single transaction.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Stores (
    Store_code INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    Store TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
)

CREATE TABLE Products ( 
    Product_Code INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Product_Name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Description TEXT, 
    Product_Date TEXT -- Is this the transaction date? 
)

-- Not exactly sure what these columns are for, 
-- so I don’t know precisely where they fit in a normalized schema
    -- Permission INTEGER, -- Not sure what this is for 
    -- Incoming INTEGER, -- Same as purchased quantity?  
    -- Outgoing INTEGER, -- Same as sold quantity? 

CREATE TABLE Sales (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    Store_code INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Stores(Store_code),
    Product_Code INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Products(Product_Code),
    TransactionDate AS DATETIME,
    Unit_Sell_Price CURRENCY NOT NULL,
    Quantity INTEGER NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Purchases (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    Store_code INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Stores(Store_code),
    Product_Code INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Products(Product_Code),
    TransactionDate AS DATETIME,
    Unit_Buying_Price CURRENCY NOT NULL,
    Quantity INTEGER NOT NULL
)
```

The following query demonstrates how to insert new purchased products.  This INSERT statement uses SQL parameter syntax to indicate that it needs input values from the language/environment external to the SQLite database.  (The details of how to properly execute such a statement --including how to pass input values-- are not described here and should be researched separately.)

```sql
INSERT INTO Sales (Store_code, Product_Code, TransactionDate, Unit_Sell_Price, Quantity)
    VALUES (@storecode, @productcode, @trandate, 
        (SELECT AVG(Unit_Buying_Price) AS AveragePrice  
         FROM Purchases 
         WHERE Store_code= @storecode AND Product_Code = @productcode), 
        @quantity)
```

Notice that total prices are not stored in either `Sales` or `Purchases` transaction tables, rather totals are calculated dynamically with a query similar to the following.

```sql
CREATE VIEW PurchaseDetails AS
    SELECT *, Unit_Buying_Price * Quantity AS Total_Buying_Price
    FROM Purchases
```

Comment: I know it shouldn't be like that. That's what I'm asking for. How to do it is the question because I couldn't find an answer for that anywhere. I'll provide the schema above and please tell me what to do If I want to achieve the outputs I expect because I really can't get to find a solution by myself. Even If I add to the where clause the line 

```
    WHERE Incoming - Outgoing > 0 

````
It would still calculate the previous 1000$ Monitor in the average if I bought new monitors.
Thanks

Comment: To make things clear. I know the database doesn't have enough conditions to do what I want. The question is what conditions should I provide to make it do as I explained.

Comment: @MohamedAmr Re-read the answer from `I suggest research data normalization.`, it is good advice.

Comment: I will. I need it for the future that's for sure. But I really need the answer to this right now. I'm so sorry and I promise I'll start reading about it but I'm running out of time to create that program. I'm sure there's a way to add a condition that does that But I really can't think of a way to do it. If you provide a way to do it I'll be very grateful and I will definitely research data normalization because it's not the first time someone says that to me.

Comment: It is difficult to tell at what level one needs assistance, but Stack Overflow is primarily for programming question where one already knows what they want to do.  Your question seems to start with basic conceptual issues that start before programming even begins.  **That is too broad for a single Stack Overflow question,** and parts of the answer are mathematical and involve knowledge of proper accounting, etc.  Sorry, but a full answer to all aspects is just more than I can offer here.

Comment: @MohamedAmr  Okay, I gave in and posted an update with more details.  I hope it helps, but there are so many questions that you need to research and answer for yourself.  If you have another specific question that you cannot answer **after requisite research**, then please post another specific question.

Comment: Yes, only existing products means it should take the average for products that are in stock (That are actually in the store right now).                                            Thanks a lot for your help and I'll research more into detail data normalization.

Comment: To answer your questions about it if you have any edits to make.                                                                                     Every row records a single transaction.                           Permission is the permission number on paper on which the product was permitted to enter the store.       Incoming is purchased quantity.                                  Outgoing is sold quantity. Thanks.